# How do I make a line graph that combines multiple entries per day over a period of time?

Tags: r, line, ggpubr

Not sure if my title makes sense, but I'm trying to graph out spending over time. Here is my dput:

```
structure(list(case = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), year = c(2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L), month = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L), day = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L), type1 = c("food", 
"food", "drink", "misc", "drink", "drink"), type2 = c("restaurant", 
"tang_kee", "coffee", "headphone", "cola", "coffee_grounds"), 
    amount = c(210, 12, 9, 50, 18, 39)), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

When I just make a simple line graph with gglines, it makes this:

```
ggline(slack_budget,
         x="case",
         y="amount")+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(title = "Progression of Spending November and December",
       subtitle = "Non-Rent / Non-Utility Spending Line Graph",
       caption = "*Data obtained from local matrix.")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        plot.caption = element_text(face = "italic"))
```

Which creates this:

[image]

As you can see here, it graphs a point for every individual entry for spending on that day. This looks a little ugly in my opinion because it doesn't really tell a picture of how much is actually being spent day to day in total.

What I'm more looking for is combining all the entries for each day without combining each month's spending (hence why I have x = case instead of x = day). If there is an easier way of achieving that, it would be great to know.

## Solution:

Thanks to Stefan for his answer. I have now created this lovely plot after aggregating the data:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to aggregate your data per day/case to show the total amount of spending per day as a line graph:

```r
library(ggpubr)

slack_budget_sum <- aggregate(amount ~ case + year + month + day, data = slack_budget, FUN = sum)

base <- ggline(slack_budget_sum,
       x="case",
       y="amount")+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(title = "Progression of Spending November and December",
       subtitle = "Non-Rent / Non-Utility Spending Line Graph",
       caption = "*Data obtained from local matrix.")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        plot.caption = element_text(face = "italic"))

base
```

[image]

And if you still want to show the single purchases you could do so via an additional `geom_point` using the original non-summarized data:

```r
base + 
  geom_point(data = slack_budget, color = "steelblue")
```

[image]

Comment: I think that's okay for showing the long term trends, but I'm more interested in the day to day or month to month patterns, so it would be good to see what the sum totals for each day are graphed onto a line graph.

Comment: Wait nevermind, thats actually exactly what I needed. Just looked different on your graph. Thanks!